# ImportError raised when trying to load 'blog.templatetags.blog_tags': No module named 'markdown

Tags: python, django

I use django 3.1.1 and Python 3.8.5

I have the same problem like in this [include() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178196/include-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-app-name) So I use a solution from the first answer, but still I have error and I don't know what to do.

This is my urls.py in blog

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .feeds import LatestPostsFeed

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    # Widoki posta.
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    #url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
        r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/share/$', views.post_share,
        name='post_share'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_list,
        name='post_list_by_tag'),
    url(r'^feed/$', LatestPostsFeed(), name='post_feed'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.post_search, name='post_search'),
]
```

This is my urls (main)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from blog.sitemaps import PostSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'posts': PostSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post, Comment
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm, SearchForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from taggit.models import Tag
from django.db.models import Count
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet


def post_share(request, post_id):
    # Pobranie posta na podstawie jego identyfikatora.
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Formularz został wysłany.
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Weryfikacja pól formularza zakończyła się powodzeniem…
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(
                                          post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) zachęca do przeczytania "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            message = 'Przeczytaj post "{}" na stronie {}\n\n Komentarz dodany przez {}: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    'sent': sent})

class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'

def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # Trzy posty na każdej stronie.
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # Jeżeli zmienna page nie jest liczbą całkowitą,
        # wówczas pobierana jest pierwsza strona wyników.
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # Jeżeli zmienna page ma wartość większą niż numer ostatniej strony
        # wyników, wtedy pobierana jest ostatnia strona wyników.
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'page': page,
                  'posts': posts,
                  'tag': tag})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish__day=day)

    # Lista aktywnych komentarzy dla danego posta.
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Komentarz został opublikowany.
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Utworzenie obiektu Comment, ale jeszcze nie zapisujemy go w bazie danych.
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Przypisanie komentarza do bieżącego posta.
            new_comment.post = post
            # Zapisanie komentarza w bazie danych.
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    # Lista podobnych postów.
    post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
    similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids)\
                                  .exclude(id=post.id)
    similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
                                 .order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]

    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post,
                   'comments': comments,
                   'comment_form': comment_form,
                   'similar_posts': similar_posts})

def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post)\
                                      .filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # Obliczenie całkowitej liczby wyników.
            total_results = results.count()
            return render(request,
                          'blog/post/search.html',
                          {'form': form,
                          'cd': cd,
                          'results': results,
                          'total_results': total_results})
    else:
        return render(request,
                      'blog/post/search.html',
                      {'form': form})
```

and my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                     self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Roboczy'),
        ('published', 'Opublikowany'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name='blog_posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager() # Menedżer domyślny.
    published = PublishedManager() # Menedżer niestandardowy.
    # Obsługa tagów.
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                             self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                             self.slug])


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Komentarz dodany przez {} dla posta {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

This is my error

```
^C(myDjangoEnv) jakub@jakub-HP-ProBook-6470b:~/Pobrane/djptas/r03/mysite$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jakub/Pobrane/djptas/r03/mysite/blog/templatetags/blog_tags.py", line 8, in <module>
    import markdown
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markdown'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'blog.templatetags.blog_tags': No module named 'markdown'
```

Comment: Have you checked if there is a markdown installed? If no `pip install Markdown`.

Comment: thank you it's worked

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked if there is a markdown installed? If no `pip install Markdown`.